# How to exclude an element when using a link

Tags: html

I have an issue right now and i am curious if there is a possible way to solve this. I have 2 `div`'s enclosed in `href` elements. The problem is that i want to exclude the `<p>` element. Is there a way to do this despite it being inside the `href` element? Thanks.

```html
<a href= "sample.com">
  <div class="1">
    <p>Hello</p>
   </div>
</a>
<a href= "test.com">
  <div class="2">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `exclude the <p>` element? Like not be able to click on it?

Comment: The HTML in your fist half is invalid. You close the link prior to closing the div. Also without the href parameter you don't even have a link.

Comment: Yes.. I want the div class only to be the one clickable. is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can but I wouldn't advocate for it.

You could use CSS to remove the appearance of a link:

```
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

p{
  cursor: default;
  color: #000;
}
```

Then you could use `preventDefault()` to prevent the `p` from triggering the action on click:

```
$("p").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sy9woxvt/3/)

What you really should do is add another wrapper to contain your elements and then wrap your `div` with an `a` like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
     <div class="1"></div>
  </a>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('p').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
    // or alert($(this).hash();
  });
});
```