# Parent div clickable between another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```css
.black {
  background-color: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">    
    <div class="black">
        <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

I'm trying to make the whole div "black" clickable with an hyperlink, but without the div "red" area with any success. I don't know if I should solve it with css or JS, or simply just HTML5

Comment: Soooo... you don't want `.red` to link to `.black` `href` attribute when clicking `.black`?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to reach :)

Comment: it's just impossible to achieve this, because the `red` `div` is contained in the black one, so, when you are clicking in the black is like you clicking in the red

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude an element when using a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832613/how-to-exclude-an-element-when-using-a-link)

Comment: Have you try resolve this, using `pointer-events: none;`. But it will work fine with newer browsers

Comment: @TsuruleVol That will just indicate that the browser should ignore `.red` as though it wasn't even there, so even when clicking on it, you're still actually clicking `.black`.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, got it, you can simply play with `z-index`. Give your `.red { z-index:0}` & for `.black { z-index: 1}`. Hope it will help :)

Comment: @TsuruleVol Have you tested that theory? When I did, there was no cigar.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/cwqp08Lz/

Comment: @TsuruleVol well I did, and it still triggers the link on `.black` - which is specifically what the OP is trying to circumvent, as I understand it.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, just answer with demo, below the topic, hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I forgot to wrap the target with jquery object.. sorry

if you want to prevent a child element from triggering an event then can do this via jquery

```
 $('a').click( function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is('.black')) {
    console.log('whatever..');
    // or do whatever you want
   } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

as for the cursor you can do this via css

```
.red {
cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: The cursor statement merely changes the appearance of the cursor, while preventDefault is part of the standard w3c spec for events, not a "jquery" thing.

Comment: @phil where did I mentioned that `preventDefault()` is part of Jquery?! the script works and it does what he wants.. beside why don't you post your solution genius instead of downvoting other members..

Comment: Good that you corrected `e.target.is`. Before it was throwing **e.target.is is not a function**. I created a fiddle for your current answer. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jbyjrvha/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.stopPropagation`:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">    
    <div class="black">
        <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(".black").click(function(e) {
  alert("black");
});

$(".red").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.black {
  background-color: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/korwx3qv/2/)

Comment: Works perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth exploring a different approach here, in terms of structuring.

1. Remove `.mr-red` from `.mr-black`
2. Wrap `.mr-red` and `.mr-black` in `.mr-brown`
3. Position `.mr-red` `absolute` and place accordingly within `.mr-brown`, overlaying `.mr-black`

```css
.mr-brown {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

.mr-black {
  background-color: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.mr-red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mr-brown">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="mr-black"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="mr-red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is taking liberties with selector names a good enough reason for a downvote? I don't think so.

Comment: This answer also looks promising. +1. [EXAMPLE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv6txxqf/)

Answer (score 0):

I would separate them completely and use absolute positioning to put the red square in the right place.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="black">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const clickableBox = document.querySelector(".black")
const anchor = document.querySelector("a")
anchor.addEventListener("click", (e) =>
    e.target !== clickableBox && e.preventDefault())
```

https://jsfiddle.net/korwx3qv/4/

Answer (score 0):

That is so interest issue. Please, take a look here:

```
<a href="#">    
    <div class="black">
        <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

---

```
.black {
  background-color: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  cursor: default;
}
```

---

```
 $('a').click( function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is('.black')) {
    alert('.black');    
   } 
  });
```

---

And demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/kkz6y7uo/2/

Hope it would help you :)